# Div elements in position relative will not stack

Tags: html, css

In summary, I made a container div (parent) with a position: relative, then added 3 children divs with position: absolute. I am now trying to add another div that is below all of this, i.e. the next section of a website. But now the next div appears under the first main "parent" div. From endless searching on here and google I though a main div with position relative would not destroy the flow, but obviously it did or else I would't be posting.

I now want to have another div outside of the parent so that it will go under this first div and make for a nice, scolling website. Please look at my CSS and help me understand why the absolute elements inside a relative element messed up the flow. (I'm new to CSS, so any pro tips are appreciated!)

[Here is an image of the website so you get a feel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zycvg.jpg)

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans HK', sans-serif;
}

/* Arranging the parent and child elements so 
images can overlap */

.child {
    top: 0;
}
.child-1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

.child-2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.child-3 {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 38%;
    left: 0;
    
}
#parent {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    
}

.hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    right: 10vw;
    top: 28vw;
    z-index: 9;
    font-size: 3.5vw;
    float: right;
    color: white;
}

/* Responsive viewport area, 
Logo resize based on the screen size */

#logo_png {
    max-width: 25vw;
}

#hero_img {
    max-width: 85vw;
    
}

#green_circle_png {
    max-width: 40vw;
}

/* NAV BAR STYLING */

#container {

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 900;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}


nav {
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5vw;   /* margin-left obly touches the left margin, not L & R */
    padding-top: 25px;

    position: relative;
}

nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.4vw;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: black;
}



.p1 {
    color: #f5f7ff;
    font-size: 10vw;
}
#test {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>

    
    
    <div id="parent">

            <div class="child child-1">
                <h1>
                    <a href='THIS WILL BE LINK TO HOME PAGE'>
                        <img id="logo_png" src="C:\Users\rebec\Desktop\LBS WEBSITE\Images\lbs_blue_circle_logo_1500x1500.png" alt="Little Big Scientists"/>
                
                    </a>
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="child child-2">
                <h1>
                    <img id="hero_img" src="Images/circle_hands_lbsphoto.png" alt="Little Big Scientists"/>
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="child child-3">
                <h1>
                    <img id="green_circle_png" src="Images/green_circle_lbswebsite.png" alt="Little Big Scientists"/>
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="hero-text">
                <p>We’re on a mission to teach,
                    <br>guide, and empower the next
                    <br> generation of scientists
                </p>
            </div>

            <!-- Div for Nav Bar-->
            <div id="container"> 

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        
            </div>

    </div>
    

    
    <div id="test">
            <h2 class="p1">Inspiring Education</h2>
    </div>
    
    <h2 class="p1">HELP MEEEE</h2>
    
    


</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, can you please point to individual elements and explain the output you require?

Comment: Your `position: absolute` elements kill the flow. Not your realtive positioned element. Remove **all** `position: absolute` and then you can have a normal scrolling website. Hint: You don't need `position: absolute` at all for your layout.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @cloned I used absolute to force the images in each section, but I can try going back and re-designing it all. oof

Comment: Maybe post an image on how your design should look like.

Comment: @cloned I added an image. Since they're all images I wanted to "force" them in their spaces, but now I know position absolute is poor code. I can't remove them or everything gets out of shape.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'll check out that site right now. I kinda jumped into the project to learn but am still confused about positioning. Would you suggest I scrap it and use better code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's necessarily anything wrong with using absolute positioning for some elements. The main problem you are experiencing is that because everything inside #parent is absolute positioning #parent collapses and has zero height. If you want to do overlapping circles, absolute positioning is a valid way to do it, but you have to expressly set a height for #parent.

Below is a modified copy of your code. I want to emphasize it is a **very** rough starting point, and by no means is it complete, but I think it demonstrates some of the things you can do. Even with absolute positioning of the circle elements it is still fairly responsive and it could be made fully responsive by adding appropriate media queries to the css.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans HK', sans-serif;
}

/* Arranging the parent and child elements so 
images can overlap */
 
.child {
    position: absolute;
}
.child-1 {
    top: -75px;
    left: -75px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    max-width: 50vw;
    max-height: 50vw;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.child-1 h1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 20%;
  background: white;
  
}
.child-2 {
    right: -40vw;
    top: -50vw;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 120vw;
    height: 120vw;
    background: center / contain no-repeat url("./Images/circle_hands_lbsphoto.png"), content-box linear-gradient(lightgray, lightgray);
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}

.child-3 {
    top: 60vh;
    left: -5vw;
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    max-width: 50vw;
    max-height: 50vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: lightgreen;
    
}
#parent {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 550px;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: 40%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 60%;
    z-index: 9;
    font-size: 3.5vw;
    color: white;
}

/* Responsive viewport area, 
Logo resize based on the screen size */

#logo_png {
    max-width: 25vw;
}

#hero_img {
    max-width: 85vw;
    
}

#green_circle_png {
    max-width: 40vw;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 20%;
}

/* NAV BAR STYLING */

#container {
    z-index: 900;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
}


nav {

}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5vw;   /* margin-left obly touches the left margin, not L & R */
    padding-top: 25px;

    position: relative;
}

nav a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.4vw;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: black;
}



.p1 {
    color: #f5f7ff;
    font-size: 10vw;
}
#test {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="parent">
            <div class="child child-1">
                <h1>
                    <a href='THIS WILL BE LINK TO HOME PAGE'>
                        <img id="logo_png" src="C:\Users\rebec\Desktop\LBS WEBSITE\Images\lbs_blue_circle_logo_1500x1500.png" alt="Little Big Scientists 1"/>   
                    </a>
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="child child-2">
                
                    <img id="hero_img" alt="Little Big Scientists 2"/>
              
                <div class="hero-text">
                <p>We’re on a mission to teach,
                    <br>guide, and empower the next
                    <br> generation of scientists
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="child child-3">
                <h1>
                    <img id="green_circle_png" src="Images/green_circle_lbswebsite.png" alt="Little Big Scientists 3"/>
                </h1>
            </div>
    </div>
     <!-- Div for Nav Bar-->
            <div id="container"> 

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        
            </div>

    
    <div id="test">
            <h2 class="p1">Inspiring Education</h2>
    </div>
    
    <h2 class="p1">HELP MEEEE</h2>
    
    


</body>
```

Comment: This is really helpful in understanding how elements can work together, thank you! I was able to fix it by only throwing the blue logo image in position absolute since I don't care if it goes out of the website flow. The one that I need to be in the flow is the main image, so I made it normal and it slid nicely under the logo since it was no longer considered there. Since the div is so big, the rest of the website now stacks nicely underneath. I see what you're saying about height and that helped me to understand what happens in the CSS. All the best!